# How to replace a group of characters for "" in c++?

Tags: c++

I looked over here

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace

But that seems to be like just for one string a time i dont want to run a `for` for each character i have. Is there a way this replace method to run with a `vector<string>` or some array of characters?

Like "i like l/e*m)o)n.s" turn into "i like lemons".

```
replace(arrayOfcharacters, "");  something like that...
```

Is there a way?

Comment: I don't think such library function is available.. But you can still write your own code for it..

Comment: I want something like "msg = msg.replace(regexpAcceptChars, '');" in as3, where regexpAcceptChars:RegExp = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9çãõáéíóúÇÁÉÍÓÚàÀÃÕ=:\(\)\$\@\,\.\?\-\;]"+sep+"]", 'g');

Comment: I dont want to run 2 or 3 for's

Comment: The C++ regex library has a replace function and it appears you understand regular expressions.  Generally SO users don't like writing code blocks for people, try writing a function which does what you want and if you have trouble you can come back and ask us to help you figure out what is wrong with it.  AFAIK, there is not a standard library function which takes a vector of strings, but it should not be that difficult to do a for loop through the vector and call replace on each string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expression for that:

```
std::string text = "i like l/e*m)o)n.s";
std::regex rx("/|\\*|\\)|\\(|\\.");

auto result = std::regex_replace(text, rx, "");
```

Comment: yep, that's the spirit

Comment: Thats what i wanted... Two question as a new c++ user... Do i need to use std:: everytime and this result variable cant be a string? whats is this auto?

Comment: You can say `using namespace std` and then you don't need to qualify everything with `std::`. `auto` is a feature in C++11 that tells the compiler to deduct the type of the expression on the right. In this example is equivalent to `std::string result`.

Comment: Im getting _STL namespace has no member "regex"

Comment: What compiler are you using? This is available in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

If stripping characters is what you want (as your example seems to indicate) then [the remove algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) should work.  The page includes some example code that should point you in the right direction.